# Как правильно сделать фильтрацию контента?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, frontend

Вопрос собственно не очень сложный, мне кажется. Я только обучаюсь :)
Вкратце, есть 10 карточек, одни, условно, синие, другие - красные. У этих карточек есть 2 класса, 1-й класс cards, который задает им размеры, бордер, синий цвет и т.д. 2-й класс cards--red, который перебивает только синий цвет красным.
Так же есть чекбокс, при нажатии на который на странице должны отображаться только красные карточки.
Думал сделать довольно просто, дать какой-нибудь переменной querySelectorAll('.cards'), после чего обработать нажатие на чекбокс addEventListener, чтобы к карточкам с классом .cards добавлялся класс .cards--inactive (который заранее есть в css с display: none).
Однако, как оказалось, querySelectorAll особо не разбирается 1 класс у блока, или 2, и загребает ноду сразу же как находит cards) По итогу при нажатии на чекбокс отключаются все карточки, т.к. класс cards--inactive с display:none добавляется ко всем карточкам.
Вот собственно и вопрос, как можно такое провернуть?) Только html,css,js.
Заранее спасибо всем за ответы.

Comment: Покажите часть html с вашими карточками и js, как вы пытаетесь их выбрать. Для этого нажмите править ниже вашего вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Накидал на скорую руку, уверен, что Вы сможете подогнать под себя. Код:

```
// JS
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card")
const checkbox = document.querySelector(".checkbox")



checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    if (cards[i].className !== 'card red' && checkbox.checked) {
      cards[i].classList.add("inactive");
    } else {
      cards[i].classList.remove("inactive");
    }
  }
})
```

```
/* CSS */
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.inactive {
  display: none;
}
```

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="card red"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card red"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
</div>
```

Поиграться с кодом можно тут:
https://codepen.io/listopad02/pen/eYKLQwm

P.S. в следующий раз прилагайте свой код, чтобы задача была более понятна. Тут так принято

Comment: понял, спасибо большое за ответ. Пока был в спортзале придумал другой алгоритм, вот такой (если интересно) : https://codepen.io/CallMeHamster/pen/MWXqzvL

Comment: @GorkaChannel, практически идентичное решение, разве что очень рекомендую обращаться к элементам страницы через const, а не let

Comment: Но вы немного не так поняли, видимо я плохо объяснил... У нас карточки с двумя классами, т.е. <div class="card card--red"></div> --- это красная карточка, а синяя будет с одним классом card

Comment: а можете объяснить причину пожалуйста? почему через const

Comment: @GorkaChannel, const создает константу, а не переменную. То есть, значение нельзя перезаписать. Делая так, вы будете уверены, что создав константу с элементом страницы, она останется этой константой навсегда и не будет случайно перезаписана